# How to make smooth inputs in python turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to make a pong game. Inside it, I want to have a smooth moving paddle with the inputs (e.g. press w and it will move up without going once, then repeating as the key is pressed) I want it to just start repeating as the key is pressed. So as soon as you press the key it won't slightly jolt up and then start moving, it will just smoothly move up.

```
game: bool = True

win = turtle.Screen()
win.setup(width=800, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)

# Functions
def paddle_a_up():
    if paddle_a.ycor() + 70 < 300:
        y = paddle_a.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddle_a.sety(y)


def paddle_a_down():
    if paddle_a.ycor() - 70 > -300:
        y = paddle_a.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddle_a.sety(y)


def paddle_b_up():
    if paddle_b.ycor() + 70 < 300:
        y = paddle_b.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddle_b.sety(y)


def paddle_b_down():
    if paddle_b.ycor() - 70 > -300:
        y = paddle_b.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddle_b.sety(y)


# Keyboard binding
win.listen()
win.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
win.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "W")
win.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
win.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "S")
win.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
win.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")

while game:
    win.update()
```

Comment: `onkeypress` should only set global variable ie. `move_up = True`, and `onkeypress` should set `move_up = False`. And in `while game` you should check `move_up` and move it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onkeypress` should only set global or class variable ie. `move_up = True`,
`onkeyrelease` should set `move_up = False`,
and in `while game` you should check `move_up` and move paddle.

I made it only for left paddle. You have to do the same for right paddle.

And I use speed `2` instead of `20` because now it was moving too fast.

```
import turtle

game: bool = True

win = turtle.Screen()
win.setup(width=800, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("blue")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("red")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)

# default value at start
paddle_a.move_up = False
paddle_a.move_down = False

# Functions
def paddle_a_up_start():
    paddle_a.move_up = True

def paddle_a_up_end():
    paddle_a.move_up = False
    
def paddle_a_down_start():
    paddle_a.move_down = True

def paddle_a_down_end():
    paddle_a.move_down = False


def paddle_b_up():
    if paddle_b.ycor() + 70 < 300:
        y = paddle_b.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
    if paddle_b.ycor() - 70 > -300:
        y = paddle_b.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddle_b.sety(y)


# Keyboard binding
win.listen()

win.onkeypress(paddle_a_up_start, "w")
win.onkeyrelease(paddle_a_up_end, "w")

win.onkeypress(paddle_a_up_start, "W")
win.onkeyrelease(paddle_a_up_end, "W")

win.onkeypress(paddle_a_down_start, "s")
win.onkeyrelease(paddle_a_down_end, "s")

win.onkeypress(paddle_a_down_start, "S")
win.onkeyrelease(paddle_a_down_end, "S")


win.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
win.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")


while game:
    if paddle_a.move_up:
        if paddle_a.ycor() + 70 < 300:
            y = paddle_a.ycor()
            y += 2
            paddle_a.sety(y)

    if paddle_a.move_down:
        if paddle_a.ycor() - 70 > -300:
            y = paddle_a.ycor()
            y -= 2
            paddle_a.sety(y)

    win.update()
```